# Using .htaccess with pdf on OS X with Firefox

Tags: macos, .htaccess, pdf, web, mime

I'm trying to have a directory point to a pdf file. So in the directory I have a .htaccess file that says:

```
DirectoryIndex vitae.pdf
```

This works great on every distribution of Windows and Linux that I have tried. However, if I go to the directory using a machine with Firefox 13 on OS X 10.7, it tries to download the file with a weird filename (e.g. "59GFLAOl.dms-1.part") and fails to open it.

I have tried adding lines such as:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

and

```
ForceType application/pdf
```

But I have had no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: Does it do this in all browsers? What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that part! It seems to work in all browsers except Firefox (13) on OS X (10.7).